# what analog hotkeys in Xaml visual studio 2012 metro app Ctrl M, O for collapses all codeblocks

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, codeblocks, hotkeys

What analog hotkeys in **Xaml** visual studio 2012 metro app `Ctrl M, O` for collapses all codeblocks

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/da5kh0wa.aspx#editors), CTRL+M, CTRL+L (look for `Edit.ToggleAllOutlining`).